# Running PyTorch multiprocessing in a Docker container with Gunicorn worker manager

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, multiprocessing, pytorch, gunicorn

- I am trying to deploy a service on GCP. It's a Docker container that uses Gunicorn for worker management.
- The code runs a torch.multiprocessing.process to run a POST response as a background process.

This works if I run the script using a python3 command. But hangs when using Gunicorn.

- My understanding is that CUDA needs threadsafe multiprocessing and that is why torch has its own implementation. When we set up Gunicorn to manage workers, this may be causing some conflict or thread safety issues.

Has anyone come across this before. Would there be a different worker manager that I could be using?

In Dockerfile: CMD gunicorn -w 1 -t 6000 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 --timeout 6000 --preload app_script:app - this is how i am running the app in docker. So yes I am using preload. And the issue happens even if I run the docker container locally so its not just a gcp situation

p=torch.multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function args=(args, )) . p.start() - this is how a post call is getting handled.

Comment: Could you add more details like, how are you deploying on GCP and how have you bootstrapped your APIs with gunicorn? Also, since loading model is resource heavy, it is recommended to "preload" it. Have you done that?

Comment: In Dockerfile - CMD gunicorn -w 1 -t 6000 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 --timeout 6000 --preload app_script:app - this is how i am running the app in docker. So yes I am using preload. And the issue happens even if I run the docker container locally so its not just a gcp situation

Comment: p=torch.multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function args=(args, )) .         
p.start() - this is what happens in a post call

Comment: Aren't -t and --timeout same? Also, can you add output of docker container logs using - `docker logs <container_id>`

Comment: Are you deploying this on Compute Engine or in what GCP product?

Comment: kubernetes microservice - but this happens even if you run the docker image locally using gunicorn

Answer (score 6):

I spent a lot of time investigating a similar issue.
Pytorch calls were stuck when running on a docker container with gunicorn.

The solution that worked for me was removing the `--preload` flag from the Docker gunicorn command.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, NitzanS answer worked for me. Another solution is setting the number of threads PyTorch uses:

```
import torch
torch.set_num_threads(1)
```